# Record audio while using the Voice Typing feature

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I am developing an Android 4.0 (`minSDKVersion=14`) app where I want to record the audio that is spoken while using the Voice Typing feature (via the little microphone icon on the softkeyboard).

The recording component via `MediaRecorder` is not the issue here. What I am searching is a way to tap into the Voice Typing function, like a Listener that is called when the user presses the microphone button.

I tried different things like subclassing `EditView` and implementing the `onKeyPreIme()` method for capturing the microphone button event or working with the `RecognitionListener` interface. But that is all too much cruft around a simple need. I want to keep the default Voice Typing functionality and just be notified when the recognition starts (and ends). Any ideas?